# Is that possible by only using while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

My tutor gave me an assignment where I have to write a code that only contains while loop and prints:

```
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1
```

I tried it 100 times and failed 100 times. Due to my limited knowledge, I began to think that my tutor is just messing with my brain. If it's possible,  please introduce me a code that prints the numbers in that order.
Thanks...

Comment: Do you know any other solution to print this pattern, like using `for` loop? Or can you show some code that you tried?

Comment: Are those spaces before numbers intentional?

Comment: I don't yet started with for loops.

Comment: There are a great many ways to do this.  A key decision is whether to keep the value to output each time through the loop in a `std::string` or say an `int`.  For the former, you can prepend successive characters '2', '3', '4' etc. (or if you store it with spaces, overwrite the next space using indexing a la `[n]`); for the latter add 20, 300, 4000 etc...

Comment: Adding your code from your best of tries could help us identify what's missing in your solution. i'd just counted the preceding spaces(on line 1) that comes to a total of 8

Comment: @Tony  Will you please write a snippet for what you saying.

Comment: You tried hundred times and still can't seem to share even one of your failed attemts?

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal: I could, but I deliberately gave you enough of a hint that you could go and try again....

Comment: ... using while loop*s* or a *single* while loop?

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal check my answer below

Comment: Ok...give me some time.@Nishant

Comment: Please read 3) at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . School assignments and such are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int i = 1;
    int LIMIT = 5;
    while (i <= LIMIT)
    {
        int j = 1;
        while (j <= LIMIT -i)   //Loop to print the desired space.
        {
            cout << " ";
            j++;
        }
        int k = i;             
        while(k)
        {
            cout<<k;               //Printing the digits
            k--;
        }
        cout << endl;         //Adding new line character at the end.
        i++;
    }
```

Say hello to your tutor :)

Comment: That worked...thanks Nishant. Sure...don't tell him that you helped. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try some code like below. i've also create a sample working code here http://goo.gl/gJqias

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int start_Index=1, maximum_Index=5;
while(start_Index<=maximum_Index)
{
   //below loop prints leading whitespaces
   //note that there are two whitespaces per number
   int temp_var=start_Index;

   while (maximum_Index-temp_var>0)
   {
     cout <<"  ";
     temp_var++;//note the post increment operator.
   }

   //below whiel loop prints lagging numbers with single whitespace before them
   temp_var=start_Index;
   while(temp_var>0)
   {
        cout<<" "<<temp_var--;//note the post decrement operator.
   }
   //Now we start over to next line
   cout<<endl;      
   //Increment the start_index by 1 
   start_Index++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did that really result in the prescribed output? I'd expect it to only print 1's.

Comment: Still, did that really result in the prescribed output? It looks like it will print 1, 12, 123 and so on.

Comment: Hey skyking...I am also nesting whiles to do the job. I defined two parent while loops, one that contains a while which is responsible to print spaces and second parent while contains a child that is responsible to print the integers.

Comment: Still does not produce the required output.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[11] = "          ";// Filled with 10 blank spaces
    int i=0;
    while(i < 5)
    {
        str[9 - 2*i] = (i+1) + 48;// +48 will give equivalent ASCII code
        printf("%s\n",str);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this answer down voted? it compile and give right output. https://ideone.com/yA0doO